# Expected a "," Error in keil

Tags: c, embedded, keil

Error:

> ../Src/main.c(107): error:  #253: expected a ","

code part:

```
uint8_t maskPWR_MGMT_2[2] = {0x6c, 0b00000111};//6c
```

Comment: Don't want to be rude, but this is electronics forum. Also your problem is before this line, there's nothing wrong with this line. Please post the entire code so we can help you properly.

Comment: The 0b prefix might not be supported by this particular compiler or it is configured to disable support for it. They are usually non-standard extensions and became standard around C++14.

Comment: @Justme this is embedded C...

Comment: @Justme you are right. i just removed 0b ,and error gone ,Thanks                            ../Src/main.c(97): warning:  #177-D: variable "maskPWR_MGMT_1"  was declared but never referenced
      uint8_t maskPWR_MGMT_2[2] = {0x6b, 00000001};    //6b

Comment: @andrew Yes it is. What do you mean? You can write embedded C++ just like you can write embedded C. If this Keil compiler is not made to use C++14 standard or has no extensions to support the 0b prefix then it has no support for 0b prefix.

Comment: @Justme I've used Keil compiler before, but I've got to say, I did not see this coming. Well done

Comment: It is odd.  every gcc compiler I've used supports literal binaries in the form of 0b.  It is a language extension, but gcc should recognize it.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Yes gcc would, but Keil comes with armcc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compiler does not seem to support 0b prefix for entering numbers in binary. You need to convert it to something else, like hex or decimal.